# MySQL results of one table out of two not updating

Tags: java, netbeans-8

This is my code and i was trying to update 2 tables.But only one table updates with this code. And no error messages appear as well.

Code:

```
DefaultTableModel RecordTable = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
int selectedRow = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
 
String sql ="UPDATE `sales` SET `Username`=?,`Type`=?,`Size`=?,`Unit_Price`=?,`Quantity`=?,`Total`=? WHERE `Type`=?";
String sql2 ="UPDATE `orders` SET `Username`=?,`Total`=? WHERE `Username`=? AND `Total` ";
try {
    pst =dbConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
    
    String type = jComboBox_type.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String size =jComboBox_size.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String qty = jSpinner1.getValue().toString();
    String tot = String.valueOf(total);
    String uprice = String.valueOf(price);
    int grstot = Integer.parseInt(jTextField_finaltot.getText())-Integer.parseInt(RecordTable.getValueAt(selectedRow, 4).toString());
    finaltotal = grstot +total;
    jTextField_finaltot.setText(String.valueOf(finaltotal));
    String u = jTextField_usn.getText();
    
    RecordTable.setValueAt(type,jTable1.getSelectedRow(),0);
    RecordTable.setValueAt(size,jTable1.getSelectedRow(),1);
    RecordTable.setValueAt(uprice,jTable1.getSelectedRow(),2);
    RecordTable.setValueAt(qty,jTable1.getSelectedRow(),3);
    RecordTable.setValueAt(tot,jTable1.getSelectedRow(),4);
    
    pst.setString(1, u);
    pst.setString(2,type );
    pst.setString(3,size );
    pst.setString(4,uprice);
    pst.setString(5,qty );
    pst.setString(6,tot);
    pst.setString(7, type);

    result =pst.executeUpdate();
    
    
    pst2 =dbConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql2);
    pst2.setString(1, u);
    pst2.setString(2,tot);
    pst2.setString(3,u);
    pst2.setString(4,tot);
    
   
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Record Updated");
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Pizza_Menu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

I was unable to sort out the problem here. please help to find out it!

Comment: I guess you are missing the `pst2.executeUpdate()` command

Comment: I may be mistaken, but `AND \`Total\` "` seems to be missing something.